# Recruitment app Platform Fundamentals

Tags: force.com

I have a developer edition account. Everything was going smoothly until the middle part of chapter 7
my account only have 2 salesforce license I created 14 users by deactivating the previous account then create a new one.

After that the exercise tells me to share objects to a different user. But I can't share an object with an inactive user account because the user will not appear in the available picklist in the sharing information window. 
the activity title is "**Try It Out: Verify that Everything Works**"

How can I share the objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can reactivate an inactive user by clicking on the active checkbox on the user record. You can have 2 users with salesforce license, thereby sharing the records between those users

More info on licenses available on developer edition
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Edition